# Looking for a large corpus of business processes

Tags: uml, bpel, bpmn, statechart, business-process

I am looking, for research purposes, for a large set of examples of business processes, preferably from industry or realistic sources. The process description can be in any format, including, but not limited to:

- BPEL or BPMN
- UML Activity, Sequence of State Diagrams, including Statecharts
- Good-old Data Flow Diagrams, and variants such as OPM and Odell's notation

Reverse-engineering the process description from code is not an option, I specifically need human-written models.

I know that this is a haywire search, but thanks in advance nevertheless!

Comment: Business processes are among the confidential information. Don't expect anyone to publish their market advantage information.

Answer (score 0):

[WSO2 Business Process Server](http://wso2.com/products/business-process-server) provides a complete web-based graphical console to deploy, manage and view processes with human task capabilities. It is Powered by the Apache Orchestration Director Engine (ODE) BPEL engine.

Please checkout [BPS 3.0 alpaha release](http://www.google.lk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=wso2%20business%20process%20server%203.0.0%20alpha%20released&source=web&cd=4&ved=0CF0QFjAD&url=http://markmail.org/message/6riwpx3at6hifa6g&ei=xFMCUPPyEIephAfsxMWICA&usg=AFQjCNEoPXp-VQjVjJB12-_nVinBnCGxhQ) pack from [here](http://people.wso2.com/~sanjayav/WSO2BPS-3.0.0-Alpha/).

[WSO2 Developer Studio](http://wso2.com/products/developer-studio/) provides eclipse based development environment to develop deployable artifacts on BPS engine.

Thanks

Thilini

Comment: This is not what I asked; I am looking for a collection of business process examples, not a BP execution engine.

Comment: You can find set of samples from here https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/platform/branches/4.0.0/products/bps/3.0.0/modules/samples/product/src/main/resources/

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, but most of these are labeled "test" or "sample", not exactly realistic. I don't need reference examples, but real-life processes.